# Pros and Cons of different string types in C++

Tags: c++, string, cstring

Sorry to start another of those unanswerable questions on SO, but I'm just curious as to the pros and cons of all the different string types in C++.  My particular question is between MFC's CStrings and std::string (since I'm doing Windows only software), but this would extend to any of the string formats in C++.  What do you all thing is the best string type to use in C++ and why?

UPDATE:  I actually found a duplicate question. Thanks to those who already answered.  Please direct any new responses to this other question:  [How do you handle strings in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133364/how-do-you-handle-strings-in-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you handle strings in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133364/how-do-you-handle-strings-in-c)

Answer (score 7):

When in Rome, do as the Romans do.  If you're using MFC, use CString because the classes are all optimized for it.  Anything else, use std::string, because it's the standard and you'll find the experience useful in other contexts.

Answer (score 5):

std::string

1. It's part of the STL
2. It's portable.
3. Used correctly it can be as efficient as c-strings
4. It's safer than c-strings.

Answer (score 3):

To summarize...

**std::string Pros:**

- Portable
- STL & Boost Algorithm Support
- Safer than CStrings

**std::string Cons:**

- Conversion to CString for MFC could be slower

**CString Pros:**

- MFC functions optimized for CString

**CString Cons:**

- Not Portable
- No Boost or STL Algorithm Support

Answer (score 1):

std::string can be manipulated by boost string algorithms in addition to the ones in STL. For me the support libraries for std::string just beat MFC hands down.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the problems with c++ string types come from one or another string type requiring too large a memory overhead. That said, it also can become onerous if you have to convert from one string type to another. If you are building a large app, I suggest having a policy on which strings to use.